# robot_state_publisher electric issue

Tags: robot-state-publisher, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I moved from Diamondback to Electric and I have some issues with the robot_state_publisher.
Simply put the problem is: /tf published does not contain all the frames. Note that this was working well on diamondback.

To elaborate:
/joint_state are published @100Hz from an Orocos component and one of them looks like the following.

```
header: 
  seq: 30197
  stamp: 
    secs: 0
    nsecs: 0
  frame_id: arm_0_link
name: ['arm_1_joint', 'arm_2_joint', 'arm_3_joint', 'arm_4_joint', 'arm_5_joint', 'arm_6_joint', 'arm_7_joint']
position: [0.85575544023703909, -0.60253893146418169, 0.69191502336820099, -0.69900108242376158, -0.69835294705758466, -0.10636135673431404, -0.29402346125214407]
velocity: []
effort: []
```

The /tf published by the joint_state_publisher(in electric) is the following:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1320055266
    nsecs: 436124783
  frame_id: /base_link
child_frame_id: /arm_0_link
transform: 
  translation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.01
  rotation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
    w: 1.0
```

All the other Frames are missing.

This is my launch file:

```
<launch>

  <!-- Load arm into parameter server -->
  <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find re_kuka)/description/robots/lbr.urdf.xacro'" />

  <!-- State publisher -->
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" >
  </node>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" output="screen" name="rviz" />
</launch>
```

FYI:

- I don't see any parsing errors when I launch. I checked the urdf file using:

  ```
   demoelec@totoro:~$rosrun xacro xacro.py /home/demoelec/ros/stacks/trajectory-generator/re_kuka/description/robots/lbr.urdf.xacro > lbr.urdf
      demoelec@totoro:~$ rosrun urdf check_urdf lbr.urdf
   robot name is: lbr
   ---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
   root Link: base_link has 1 child(ren)
       child(1):  arm_0_link
           child(1):  arm_1_link
               child(1):  arm_2_link
                   child(1):  arm_3_link
                       child(1):  arm_4_link
                           child(1):  arm_5_link
                               child(1):  arm_6_link
                                   child(1):  arm_7_link
  ```
- robot_state_publisher is running and corresponding topics were published

  demoelec@totoro:~$ rosnode ping /robot_state_publisher
  rosnode: node is [/robot_state_publisher]
  pinging /robot_state_publisher with a timeout of 3.0s
  xmlrpc reply from http://totoro:38288/  time=0.640869ms

  demoelec@totoro:~$ rostopic hz joint_states
  subscribed to [/joint_states]
  average rate: 100.008
  min: 0.009s max: 0.010s std dev: 0.00013s window: 98

  demoelec@totoro:~$ rostopic hz tf
  subscribed to [/tf]
  average rate: 50.040
  min: 0.019s max: 0.021s std dev: 0.00049s window: 49

To reproduce:

```
git clone git@github.com:IDSCETHZurich/trajectory-generator.git
roscd re_kuka/launch (no need to rosmake)
rosbag play ./joint_states.bag -l 
roslaunch ./visualize.launch
```

I would appreciate any help/hints solving this.

Best Regards,
Gajan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11738/robot_state_publisher-electric-issue/) by [gajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/201/gajan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I notice your joint_states has an emtpy time stamp, and inside robot_state_publisher there is a line like:

```
if (state->header.stamp >= last_published + publish_interval_){
```

So.. you probably need to get Orocos to publish a valid timestamp.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/201/gajan/) on 2011-10-31**:
Thank you ! Adding the time stamp simply solved it !